# Is it possible to make a photo's EXIF look like it was taken with a DSLR?

Tags: dslr, metadata, mirrorless, school

My teacher doesn't want me to use my mirrorless camera to take pictures, she only wants DSLR. She wants me to rent one (which costs money). I'm obviously not going to do that lol!

My mirrorless has a manual mode and everything. Is changing the model in the EXIF the only thing I have to do? Or are there other parameters that I have to change?
Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Did you ask for her reasons for using DSLRs only?

Comment: Definitely ask her, nowadays the only sure difference between a DSLR and a mirrorless is the mirror, meaning it is capable of the same quality, speed and control.

Comment: @Itai Size and weight can also differ greatly.

Comment: I say forget asking her and just use mirrorless. There's no difference between the two in terms of learning photography. This sounds like one of those requirements that wasn't thought out properly by someone who doesn't even know what mirrorless is, and probably won't think of checking the exif.

Answer (score 18):

Yes, it is possible. But you should not do this. Being dishonest with your teacher is never a good move. If you have a mirrorless interchangeable lens camera with a large sensor, you may be able to convince your teacher that what you have is significantly close to a DSLR to work for the needs of the class. It's probably a good idea to ask exactly what she's looking for — it may be more than manual mode.  Otherwise, explain your financial difficulty. And if neither of those work, look for a different class. You're not going to get the most out of it by cheating.

Answer (score 1):

I support the idea of not cheating. Nevertheless, you can edit your exif data online via : [www.thexifer.net](http://www.thexifer.net/).

Every field can be edited. First, you upload your image on the website then you edit the EXIF data, finally you download the modified image.

Comment: I support the idea of cheating here. Teachers need to accept that their students are customers.

Answer (score 1):

Don't be dishonest. Remove the EXIF completely. And mix your pictures with some taken with a borrowed DSLR. Then see if she can prove that specific pictures were taken with a mirrorless.

Comment: @PeterTaylor fixed

Answer (score 0):

Addendum: Be aware that older but functional DSLRs can run very cheap on the used market. If the class isn't about lowlight photography or working with extreme crops, something like a Canon 40D, Nikon D200, Pentax K10D could prove perfectly adequate - these are all older generation semi-professional DSLRs, having a lower resolution sensor with less high-ISO capabilities and sometimes more conservative color rendering straight out of camera. Still great for a lot of tasks. These tend to be available around a 100 quid (make sure you get a working battery AND CHARGER with them!), plus maybe 50 for a kit and/or normal lens. If you go the Nikon or Pentax route, the lenses you get are easily adaptable to most mirrorless systems too (less so with the EOS, making these lenses work always involves electronics). The Pentax has the advantage that it can use cheap SD cards instead of comparatively costly CF cards.